# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException happens during menu inflation after migrating from APK to AAB

Tags: java, android, android-app-bundle

I have the following crash at line ever since I migrate from APK to AAB

```
// navigationView is com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer);
```

---

### Crash log

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080121
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue (ResourcesImpl.java:285)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue (Resources.java:1533)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.createDrawableIfNeeded (ResourceManagerInternal.java:176)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java:141)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
  at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable (AppCompatResources.java:104)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon (MenuItemImpl.java:505)
  at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems (NavigationMenuPresenter.java:605)
  at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update (NavigationMenuPresenter.java:546)
  at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView (NavigationMenuPresenter.java:128)
  at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.inflateMenu (NavigationView.java:371)
  at com.xxx.yyy.MainActivity.initNavigationView (MainActivity.java:589)
```

My device downloads the app from Google Play store. I try to decompile ( https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/ ) the binary APK file downloaded from my device.

Here's how it looks like

### activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:id="@id/top_group" android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:icon="@drawable/ic_content_paste_black_24dp_svg" android:id="@id/nav_notes" android:title="@string/nav_notes" />
    </group>
    <group android:id="@id/middle_group" android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:icon="@drawable/APKTOOL_DUMMY_121" android:id="@id/nav_archive" android:title="@string/nav_archive" />
        <item android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp" android:id="@id/nav_trash" android:title="@string/nav_trash" />
    </group>
    <group android:id="@id/bottom_group" android:checkableBehavior="none">
        <item android:icon="@drawable/APKTOOL_DUMMY_15d" android:id="@id/nav_settings" android:title="@string/nav_settings" />
        <item android:icon="@drawable/APKTOOL_DUMMY_13d" android:id="@id/nav_feedback" android:title="@string/nav_feedback" />
        <item android:icon="@drawable/APKTOOL_DUMMY_b6" android:id="@id/nav_shop" android:title="@string/nav_shop" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

I try to look for `0x7f080121` at

`res\values\public.xml`

It is

```
<public type="drawable" name="APKTOOL_DUMMY_121" id="0x7f080121" />
```

For

```
<item android:icon="@drawable/APKTOOL_DUMMY_121" android:id="@id/nav_archive" android:title="@string/nav_archive" />
```

it looks as following originally.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_archive"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_archive_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/nav_archive" />
```

The `ic_archieve_black_24p` resources are found at

```
res\drawable-xxxhdpi\ic_archive_black_24dp
res\drawable-xxhdpi\ic_archive_black_24dp
res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_archive_black_24dp
res\drawable-hdpi\ic_archive_black_24dp
res\drawable-mdpi\ic_archive_black_24dp
```

I have no idea how I can further proceed to find the root cause of the crash

The crash so far, happens on Android 9 & Android 11, Google Pixel 3a & Samsung Galaxy A21s

Comment: Same here. Did you find the root cause?

Comment: My guess is that, those crash are coming from app which is not downloaded from Google Play.